# nginx configuration for Laravel 4

Tags: nginx, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to setup my Laravel 4 project using nginx . Here is my nginx server block for laravel :

```
server {
        listen 80;

        root /home/prism/www/laravel/public;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name example.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

        }
               location ~ \.php$ {

                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
```

But my problem is , Its showing "404 not found" error for all other routes except the default one , that comes with default installation .

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is an NGINX Configuration i've used with Laravel 4 and Laravel 4.1 that works.

```
server {

    listen  80;
    server_name sub.domain.com;
    set $root_path '/var/www/html/application_name/public';
    root $root_path;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1;
    }

    location ~ \.php {

        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index /index.php;

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~* ^/(css|img|js|flv|swf|download)/(.+)$ {
        root $root_path;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

Comment: This worked for me, however I couldn't use all of your config settings. What I did was just use Nginx's current default and changed the `try_files` in `location / {}` to what you have and then add the `@rewrite` location. Now everything works dandy.

Comment: No. http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Taxing_Rewrites @RobGordijn has a much better solution.

Answer (score 13):

you could try this for location / { ... }

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

$query_string worked for me.

Comment: for me settting this under location / worked:  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;