# Getting 502 setting up Laravel 4 on Nginx machine

Tags: php, nginx, laravel, laravel-4

My original error was alot like this:

[nginx configuration for Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091405/nginx-configuration-for-laravel-4)

but after modifying the Nginx config server block heavily from advice from multiple forum topics I either get the **same** error in which the first page is displayed, but any link using a route returns 404, or I get a 502.

/nginx/sites-available/default:

```
server {

listen  80;
server_name sub.domain.com;
set $root_path '/usr/share/nginx/html/laravel/public';
root $root_path;

index index.php index.html index.htm;

try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1;
}

location ~ \.php {

    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index /index.php;

    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}

location ~* ^/(css|img|js|flv|swf|download)/(.+)$ {
    root $root_path;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
}
```

Error Log:

> 2014/01/22 16:51:12 [error] 14274#0: *1 connect() failed (111:
>   Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client:
>   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

Comment: do you have an `/etc/php5/fpm/pools/` folder ?

Comment: I have
/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
@MohammadAbuShady

Comment: look inside it for a line that says `listen`, you'll find 2, but only 1 will be uncommented, what does it say ?

Comment: listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock @MohammadAbuShady

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See your issue is that your php isn't actually listening to port 9000, try replacing

```
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
```

with this

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock
```

Then reload nginx

```
sudo service nginx reload
```

Your `502` will be gone

Comment: '2014/01/23 20:21:46 [error] 14274#0: *112 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"' @MohammadAbuShady

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what I mistyped, but after your inital answer I started to get 403 errors as well.  Copied the code from this answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285355/nginx-403-error-directory-index-of-folder-is-forbidden

Then looked at the differences carefully and fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock was definitely in there.

Comment: I got the same error message on laravel forge. For me just rebooting the server worked.

Comment: @AlexanderTaubenkorb probably you had the php service not running, and rebooting started it.