# Laravel: Moving from Apache to nginx

Tags: apache, nginx, laravel-4

I'm using digitalocean to serve my website with [Webuzo](http://www.webuzo.com/%E2%80%8E) as the cPanel.

I have a Laravel app and I changed the webserver from Apache to Nginx.

Suddenly all the routes have stopped working.

I have read this question 
[nginx configuration for Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091405/nginx-configuration-for-laravel-4)

but because I'm using Webuzo I don't know where the NGINX Configuration files I should be editing are.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the file located at /usr/local/apps/nginx/etc/conf.d/common for the NGINX configurations.

Make sure you restart the NGINX service everytime you make changes to the file for the changes to take effect

Answer (score 0):

Nginx does not support .htaccess  and all your routing is defined in .htaccess.

In order to resolve this issue you there is a feature in the Webuzo control panel by which you can set the reverse proxy and that will handle .htaccess by apache.

In simple terms just goto the Webuzo control panel->Nginx Setting.
and check the allow htacess option with apache run on port 8080.

By this, your site will work with Nginx.