# Laravel 4 Routing 404 Not Found

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, laravel-4

I have just played with Laravel some hours ago and seemed to hit a wall. I have seen similar questions here but they're about Apache

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
return 'hello world';
});
```

The routing above worked perfectly for `localhost/helloworld/public/`, however when I changed to this

```
Route::get('about', function()
{
return 'this is about';
});
```

and I used this url `localhost/helloworld/public/about`, it kept displaying 404 Not Found. Even when I tried `localhost/helloworld/public/index.php/about`, it still didn't work.

This is my nginx [default.conf](https://gist.github.com/hoanglamhuynh/0fdcca3a8b1ac2d92926)
And this is my [.htaccess](https://gist.github.com/hoanglamhuynh/f3bef4f893990c807fe3)

I have heard about enabling mod_rewrite on nginx but have't got a clue how to do that.

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Refrence taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21094770/1794539)

This is an NGINX Configuration i've used with Laravel 4 and Laravel 4.1 that works.

```
server {

    listen  80;
    server_name sub.domain.com;
    set $root_path '/var/www/html/application_name/public';
    root $root_path;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1;
    }

    location ~ \.php {

        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index /index.php;

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~* ^/(css|img|js|flv|swf|download)/(.+)$ {
        root $root_path;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

Comment: so strange, adding 
   `try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1;
    }` 
gave me "File not found."