# laravel HTTP ERROR 500 on sending files

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, nginx

I have a form that sends data with some files

everything works on localhost but on the server when I send files with form I get error of

> The (my site) page isn’t working
>
> (my site) is currently unable to handle this request.
>
> HTTP ERROR 500

I've already changed my php.ini and nginx conf to handle max post size and max file size and `client_max_body_size`

but still get the error

what is the problem?

Comment: did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543175/getting-a-500-internal-server-error-on-laravel-5-ubuntu-14-04) ?

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave yes his error occurs any where , but I see error only when I'm uploading files

Comment: make sure your file and folder permissions on your live server ..

Comment: also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24601391/ubuntu-nginx-laravel-500-internal-server-error) if this would help you out.

Comment: check your laravel log

Answer (score 0):

**Follow the quick points**
1 Check `.env` file created properly OR not.
2 Check your error log for more detail about which error 500

Probably this is because of some error exist into your site.

Comment: it does exist and which error log should i check for this error

Answer (score 0):

The error appears because of the lower version of PHP. Upgrade your PHP version in the Cpanel and create .htacces file and paste the following code.

```
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php71 .php .php7 .phtml
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```