# nginx host admin in another php container

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have set up a docker composer with 2 PHP applications in Laravel and an Nginx container.

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '2.0'
services:
 
  # PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      args:
        user: application
        uid: 1000
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: myapp/app
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    working_dir: /var/www/
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./php/laravel.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/laravel.ini
    networks:
      - app-network

  admin:
    build:
      args:
        user: application
        uid: 1000
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: myapp/admin
    container_name: admin
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    working_dir: /var/www/
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./php/laravel.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/laravel.ini
    networks:
      - app-network
 
  # Nginx Service
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.17-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "9000:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network
 
# Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Things work great when I'm reaching the `app` (`http://localhost:9000`) but I can't get `nginx` to reach the `admin` container when I access `http://localhost:9000/admin`

**nginx.conf:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    set $root_path '/var/www/public';
    
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    
    root $root_path;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }

    location /admin {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        fastcgi_pass admin:9000;
    }
}
```

**logs:**

```
app      | 172.18.0.2 -  22/Aug/2022:15:46:21 +0000 "GET /index.php" 302
nginx    | 172.18.0.1 - - [22/Aug/2022:15:46:22 +0000] "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 302 388 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
nginx    | 172.18.0.1 - - [22/Aug/2022:15:46:22 +0000] "GET /admin/login HTTP/1.1" 200 23138 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
app      | 172.18.0.2 -  22/Aug/2022:15:46:22 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work, the order of the locations was wrong and `try_files` was redirecting it to the app.
I had to use `rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?$1 break;` to be able to reach `/index.php` in the `admin` container

```
server {
    listen 80;
    set $root_path '/var/www/public';
    
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    
    root $root_path;

    location /admin {
        try_files $uri @admin_proxy;
    }

    location @admin_proxy {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?$1 break;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass admin:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass app:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }
    }

}
```

There's probably a better way to do this

Answer (score 0):

Check if `http://localhost:9000` is reachable or not via nginx.
If yes then trace the `access.log` and `error.log` file.

Check the root path `/var/www/public` seems it would be like `/var/www/`

Comment: Question updated with logs. My application is on `/var/www/` but Laravel hosts from  `/var/www/public`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091405/nginx-configuration-for-laravel-4